# Unityでスクリプトを書こうとすると「MonoBehaviourが見つかりませんでした」と表示される

Tags: unity3d

Unityで新規プロジェクトを立ち上げ、いざスクリプトを作ろうとすると
`Monobehaviourが見つからない。`となってしまいます。

以前はこんな事はなかったのですが、パソコンを変えバージョンなどを変えてからこの状態で
一度アンインストールしてUnityをダウンロードしなおしても、ずっとこの状態のままです
・・・素人の自分には何が原因で何を直せばいいのかがさっぱりわかりません

**実行環境**
Mac OS X (10.14.4)
Unity for mac ver 2019.1.3f1 personal
visual studio ver 8.0.8(build2)

**エラーメッセージ**

```
エラー：型または名前空間の名前”System"が見つかりませんでした。
  (usingディレクティブまたはアセンブリ参照が指定されている事を確認して下さい。)
   using ディレクトリは必要ありません。
```

こういったエンジンに関する項が全てエラーになっています。
ご助言を賜われたらと思いここにたどり着きました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

備考
として、unityバージョンをスクショいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: **文字**で伝えられる情報、「バージョン番号」や「エラーメッセージ」は画像ではなく文字として投稿した方が読み手にとって親切ですので検討してください。

Comment: ご指摘、助言ありがとうございます。文字情報として編集し直しました、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

1. 「System.Collection.Generics」 は、C#（.NET）の基本的なdllです。
2. Visualstudio側のプロジェクト自体に「そのdllを利用するよ」と明示する必要があります。
   　　ソリューションエクスプローラ > 参照がその一覧です。
3. ファイルの先頭に書くusing ○○は、イメージ的には「使用するクラスの名前の苗字を省略するよ」程度の意味しかありません。（苗字という表現は普通しませんが...）

Windows + Unity + VisualStudioの場合は、基本的なdll参照(UnityEngineも含めて)は追加済みで初期化されますが、
Macの場合はそこら辺どうなってるかちょっとわかりません。

最悪ソリューションエクスプローラ > 参照から手動で使用するdllを追加できるはずなので、
そこから追加してみてください。